# Correct way to handle event on main thread

Tags: c#, async-await, event-handling, .net-4.8, microsoft.visualstudio.threading

Usually when I want to handle an event on the main thread that has been invoked in a background thread, I write the following:

```
_backgroundWork.BackgroundEvent += (sender, args) => DoSomethingForUI();

private void DoSomethingForUI()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* Something for UI */ }));
}
```

However, when using the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers), I get a [warning](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD001.md) that `Invoke` is a legacy thread switching method and I should do the following:

```
_backgroundWork.BackgroundEvent += (sender, args) => DoSomethingForUI();

private async void DoSomethingForUI()
{
    await _joinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
    /* Do something for UI */
}
```

This gets rid of the warning but produces a new [warning](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD100.md) that I shouldn't use `async void` but instead should use the following:

```
_backgroundWork.BackgroundEvent += (sender, args) => DoSomethingForUI();

private void DoSomethingForUI()
{
    _joinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(async () =>
    {
        await _joinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
        /* Do something for UI */
    });
}
```

Again, this gets rid of the warning but produces *another* [warning](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD110.md). I got rid of that warning by doing the following:

```
_backgroundWork.BackgroundEvent += (sender, args) => DoSomethingForUI();

private void DoSomethingForUI()
{
    _joinableTaskFactory.Run(async () =>
    {
        await _joinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
        /* Do something for UI */
    });
}
```

This produces yet another [warning](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD102.md), however that one doesn't sound as bad as the others.

I am still confused. What is the correct way to handle a background event on the main thread?

Comment: What UI framework is that?

Comment: @Fildor It's a .NET Framework 4.8 library.

Comment: @gartenriese I think the question is more likely is it winforms, WPF, MAUI, ...?

Comment: It was, indeed. It _looks_ winforms-ish to me. But I haven#t done anything in winforms for quite a while and those new constructs - I have never seen before. So, that may have confused me. And even more if this is "legacy" Framework 4.8 ...

Comment: Reading the contents of the first Warning link, I see that the recommendation _there_ is different from what the analyzer seems to have suggested to you... (just thinking out loud)

Comment: @SomeBody It's independent of the used UI framework. This is just library code.

Comment: Then why do you bother with that? Have the client marshall that call?

Comment: @Fildor I'll keep that in mind, but I prefer a solution to my question.

Comment: Have you considered ignoring the analyzers? If it's not broken, don't fix it. Very few people on this planet know what the `JoinableTaskFactory` is, let alone use it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well, I don't know if it's broken or not. I thought that was what the analyzers were for, to tell me if something could go wrong.

Comment: Sure. But if nobody else than [Andrew Arnott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108631/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-joinabletaskfactory-runasync/54602612#54602612), who (I think) created this thing, knows what specific problem is the `JoinableTaskFactory` supposed to solve, and can't communicate sufficiently its purpose to his fellow developers, that's a hint that this specific analyzer can be ignored.

Comment: I second Theodor. As long as you keep it in .net Framework, the "legacy" idiomatic way to do this must stay supported for backwards compatibility anyway. So just mute those warnings.